# With Rails using Minitest, how can I set up RuboCop to run automatically each time tests are run with rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, rubocop

When I run the following command, I want [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) to inspect application directories I specify before tests run:

```
bundle exec rake test
```

Comment: Perhaps you should consider having a Guardfile that runs rubocop followed by tests automatically on file change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added the following task to `lib/tasks/test.rake`:

```
require 'rubocop/rake_task'

# Add additional test suite definitions to the default test task here
namespace :test do
  desc 'Runs RuboCop on specified directories'
  RuboCop::RakeTask.new(:rubocop) do |task|
    # Dirs: app, lib, test
    task.patterns = ['app/**/*.rb', 'lib/**/*.rb', 'test/**/*.rb']

    # Make it easier to disable cops.
    task.options << "--display-cop-names"

    # Abort on failures (fix your code first)
    task.fail_on_error = false
  end
end

Rake::Task[:test].enhance ['test:rubocop']
```

The result:

```
$ bundle exec rake test
Running RuboCop...
Inspecting 9 files
.........

9 files inspected, no offenses detected
Run options: --seed 55148

# Running:

...................

Finished in 1.843280s, 10.3077 runs/s, 34.7207 assertions/s.

19 runs, 64 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```